# Vue js sharing data through Bus is not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have two components

**1.Search**

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted :: SearchGas')
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: new Form({
        distributor: '',
        supplier: ''
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      let str = "distributor=" + this.form.distributor + "&supplierId=" + this.form.supplier;
      let baseUrl = 'wfengine/price_filter_gas_1/';

      Bus.$emit('cards_search_query', baseUrl + '?' + str);

      //Here I am updating Vikram
      this.$router.push('/results/' + encodeURIComponent(baseUrl + '?' + str));
    }
  }
}
```

**3.Results**

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    console.log('Component mounted :: Results');
    // console.log(this.$route.params.items);
    Bus.$on('cards_search_query', function(query) {
      console.log(query);
    })
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cardList: [],
      form: new Form({}),
      dataList: [],
      createCardList
    };
  }
}
```

And in my Appjs where I am calling all the files I am doing

`window.Bus = new Vue({});`

**Problem**

> When I redirect to the result page , I am not getting to see any
>   values in the console

Comment: Is your app SPA or you get full reload between two components?

Comment: @MU spa , If you want I can add the routes.js page

Comment: The reason is that your `Results` component is not present *in* the DOM when you `$emit`. Both needs to be loaded, there is no stack of events in Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello as explained by MU , this is how I solved it .

I installed VueX

npm install vuex --save

then in my app.js page which is the parent instance

```
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);
 const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cards_search_query: 'ss'
  }
});
```

Then in my **search page**

```
methods : {

          onSubmit(){

              let str = "distributor="+this.form.distributor+"&supplierId="+this.form.supplier;

              let baseUrl = 'wfengine/price_filter_gas_1/';

              this.$store.state.cards_search_query = baseUrl+'?'+str;
              //Here I am updating Vikram
              this.$router.push('/results/');

          }
        }
```

And in  My **Result page**

```
mounted() {
        console.log('Component mounted :: Results');
        console.log(this.$store.state.cards_search_query);
    },
```

Please Pay attention to

```
this.$store.state.cards_search_query = baseUrl+'?'+str;
```

Although using Vuex could be overKill for a simple task like this one .

Answer (score 2):

Possible reason based on the information provided is that other component is just not in the DOM when event is emitted, so it does not react for the event.

In this case, I would suggest to use route with parameter, so the first component would trigger the route `+str` or something like that and the second component would get the parameter from the route.

Other way, but in my opinion is not good in this case, is to use Vuex and store query in Vuex, so first component would commit the query to Vuex and second would get it from Vuex. However, I would suggest first solution.

If you have some data which you need to share between components but really don't want to expose it (but remember, on frontend side everything is more or less exposed, it's just matter of effort needed to get it) you could theoretically use LocalStorage as alternative solution to route parameter/Vuex.

Another solution (so many of them) is to solve your routes this way, that you would have some parent component e.g. SEARCH-PARENT with `<router-view>` and 2 nested routes with your components SEARCH-DIALOG & SEARCH-RESULTS. Dialog would emit the event as it's now, parent would react and then pass it to Results when route is changed.
Maybe this way?

Comment: yes My application is working fine with the parameter being sent through routes itself, But think about it . Like if some data I would like to share between two different routes which should not be passed on the url , Do I really need to use VueX  ?

Comment: Maybe he could use router [props](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html) also.

Comment: I have added another solutions. Maybe you will like any of them.

Comment: @MU thanks let me try the last 2 idea of yours , And you are totally right about nothing is secure in Javascript :)